# Serving ads to a specific device using mobile ad network

Tags: mobile, ads

Is it possible to serve specific ads that will appear on a specific user's mobile phone when he is using a specific app? Is the user's IMEI required for this? (This is when you are not the owner of the APP)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

### Targeting a specific user

Here's a couple of quotes from [DoubleClick AdExchange Buyer](https://support.google.com/adxbuyer/answer/3221407?hl=en) help page

**IDFA** (Identifier For Advertising) on iOS

> Every iOS device comes with an identifier that allows developers and
>   marketers to track activity for advertising purposes. It may be used
>   by advertisers to run remarketing campaigns and record purchasing or
>   downloading conversions.

**AAID** (Google Advertising ID) on Android

> Inventory bid requests from Android devices pass the AAID, which
>   provides the same type of device-specific, unique, resettable ID for
>   advertising as the IDFA. The ID for tablet devices with multiple users
>   may also be unique per user.

### Targeting a specific app

Check out section 3.2.9. the OpenRTB [spec](https://www.iab.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/OpenRTB-API-Specification-Version-2-4-DRAFT.pdf), there's an **App** object

> This object should be included if the ad supported content is a
>   non-browser application (typically in mobile) as opposed to a website.
>   A bid request must not contain both an App and a Site object. At a
>   minimum, it is useful to provide an App ID or bundle, but this is not
>   strictly required.